# How to delete element from list using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const CustomerAddress = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/customer/showAddress/",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setData(response.data);
        setisLoaded(true);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const deleteAddress = addressId => {
    let add = addressId.target.value;
    setData(data.filter(addressId => addressId != add));
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/deleteCustomerAddress/" + addressId,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        alert(response.data);
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error.response.data.message);
        console.log("Error is", error.response.data.message);
      });
  };
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isloaded, setisLoaded] = useState(false);

  let customer = null;
  if (isloaded) {
    customer = data.map(customer1 => (
      <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th> id </th> <th> House Number </th> <th> City </th>
              <th> State </th> <th> Zip Code </th> <th> Label </th>
              <th> Edit </th> <th> Delete </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th> {customer1.id} </th> <td> {customer1.house_number} </td>
              <td> {customer1.city} </td> <td> {customer1.state} </td>
              <td> {customer1.zip_code} </td> <td> {customer1.label} </td>
              <td>
                <button className="btn btn-primary"> Edit Details </button>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-danger"
                  onClick={() => deleteAddress(customer1.id)}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    ));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {customer}
      <center>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
          Add Address
        </button>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**I am trying to delete elements from list but getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.Can anyone tell me what wrong with my code.I am using filter method. to remove element from my list.....................................................................................................**

Comment: You are already passing the `id` in deleteAddress, but you are accessing `addressId.target.value` which causes the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any input, you are just passing the id to the `deleteAddress`.

So the `let add = addressId.target.value;` seems to be a leftover from some other code.

So remove that line altogether and rename the parameter to `add`

Then you also have an issue with the filtering. You use `addressId` but your data contains objects that have an `id`.

```
const deleteAddress = (addressId) => {
  setData(data.filter((address) => (address.id !== addressId)));
```

Comment: Thanks but the component is still not getting removed  can you tell me why?

Comment: @user5474425 updated the code to fix an additional issue